# TSQL query to filter directory

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-string

I'm trying to create a business directory in which I'm using the following query to pull data from 2 tables that contain the business info.

```
select * 
from BND_Listing 
left join BND_ListingCategories on BND_Listing.CatID = BND_ListingCategories.CatID
order by Company asc
```

I have a form that has 3 dropdowns I'm using to filter the above query using "Filters" that really are just components I need to add to my query above that will listen to query string values passed in by the form.

On submit of my form I'm redirecting back to the same URL but adding the following in my URL based on values selected from 3 dropdown fields.

```
filter-Category=[Category]&filter-City=[City]&filter-State=[State]
```

I've got this working correctly but am having difficulties when no value is passed into my URL. This happens when a user filters only by 1 of the 3 possible fields. To fix this I'm thinking I can create an "All" value that would be like filter-State=ALL

How can I update my query to pull data to listen for these filters in the query-string?

Any insight, examples really appreciated.

Hope I make sense I'm still new to programming.

The following query returns 0 results until all filters are set. If only 1 filter is set it crashed my application.

```
select * 
from BND_Listing
where 
    (Category = '[querystring:filter-Category]' 
     or '[querystring:filter-Category]'='All')
    and
    (City = '[querystring:filter-City]' 
     or '[querystring:filter-City]'='All')
    and
    (State = '[querystring:filter-State]' 
     or '[querystring:filter-State]'='All')
```

**UPDATE**:

Thanks for all the input everyone.

I've tried this simplified query in SQL Server Management Studio to test.

```
SELECT *
FROM BND_listing 
WHERE city = IsNull('Trinity', city)
```

It returns no results even though 'Trinity' is in fact a city in one of my records in the `BND_Listing` table.

I understand the ALL would add more filters but this basic query is still not pulling anything?

**UPDATE 2**:

On page load where I have not pressed the sort button and there are no query string values passed yet. If I want my grid to load ALL table records should I use a UNION command for my basic query.

```
select *  
from BND_Listing
```

Plus the more complex query used for filtering the results? So far all query examples below pull in nothing from my grid because of the WHERE statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you limited to just a select query that has to be placed in the plug-in? If not, I would create a stored procedure and read up on dynamic SQL. Dynamic SQL would allow you to dynamically generate and execute a completely different query based on whatever conditions you specify. With dynamic SQL, you could also dynamically generate the entire predicate instead of having to hard code each condition.

Another (less efficient) alternative would be to use LIKE instead of = in your predicate. For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM BND_Listing
WHERE Category LIKE CASE
                    WHEN [querystring:filter-Category] = 'All' THEN '%'
                    ELSE '[querystring:filter-Category]'
                  END
AND City LIKE CASE
                    WHEN [querystring:filter-City] = 'All' THEN '%'
                    ELSE '[querystring:filter-City]'
                  END
AND State LIKE CASE
                    WHEN [querystring:filter-State] = 'All' THEN '%'
                    ELSE '[querystring:filter-State]'
                  END
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to search for `'All'` for a given category when no filter is present, you can just treat an empty filter as meaning all:

```
SELECT *
FROM BND_Listing
WHERE (Category = '[querystring:filter-Category]' OR
       '[querystring:filter-Category]' = 'All' OR
       COALESCE([querystring:filter-Category], '') = '') AND
      (City = ... )
...
```

Comment: Thank you Tim i just read a bit about COALESCE to understand. So in your example (...) I would just keep going with COALESCE and include all the filters?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try something like this.

```
SELECT *
  FROM BND_listing 
 WHERE category = IsNull('[querystring:filter-Category]', category)
   AND city = IsNull('[querystring:filter-City]', city)
   AND state = IsNull('[querystring:filter-State]', state)
```

This functionality will check for an active filter if present and compare the appropriate field to ensure it matches.

In the case the filter has not been set it will compare the field to itself so it will always return a true result.

Comment: Just to clarify this is to solve the problem without adding the ALL filter. if the ALL filter is passed in it will not work. unless one of the columns is the String 'All'

Comment: I've set my form so that if no categories are selected it automatically passes the "All" string

Answer (score 1):

When you want all the records when the input is `NULL` then handle it using `IS NULL`.

```
SELECT *
FROM BND_listing 
WHERE (category = '[querystring:filter-Category]' OR [querystring:filter-Category]' is NULL)
  AND (city = '[querystring:filter-City]' OR '[querystring:filter-City]' IS NULL)
  AND (state ='[querystring:filter-State]' OR '[querystring:filter-State]' IS NULL)
```

**Note :** This method will use any `INDEX` present on `Category` or `city` or `state` where as `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` method will restrict the optimizer from using `INDEX`

Comment: Prdp, when using this query in my grid it pulls no data. Even when passing in a querysting value of ALL.

Also on pageload there is not querystring loaded until someone presses search which I would like to have all my records loaded.

Comment: Dont pass all pass Null

Comment: Even when passing Null my grid is empty. I am however modifying the query a bit using left join to attach my categories table would that affect the functionality?

Comment: @AlexP - then post the original query.. Along with sample data and expected result

Comment: i've written a secondary post on here that perhaps better explains my problem with screenshots.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607263/using-union-to-pull-data-into-grid?noredirect=1#comment66522789_39607263