# ORDER BY select statement using UNION & DISTINCT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using the following query to populate a dropdown list of values.

```
select 'Select a City' as City, 'All' as Value
UNION ALL
select distinct City, City as Value from BND_Listing
```

I'd like to sort A-Z the results. I've tried the following:

```
select 'Select a City' as City, 'All' as Value
UNION ALL
select distinct City, City as Value from BND_Listing
ORDER BY City ASC
```

But am getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Union'.

Additionally this query is pulling "Blank or NULL" values and displaying a blank space at the top of the drop-down. I'd like to hide that if possible. Not display any null value?

Comment: are you sure you gave the correct query? There is no way you get the error on your second query

Comment: To avoid blank or NULL, use WHERE clause to filter them out in your query

Comment: @techspider yes the query is correct. When I run this query in SQL Management studio it does work. When inputting into my forms plug-in i'm getting the error from your comment it looks like to be something on the plug-in side that is causing the error?

Do you have an example of how to filter out the NULLS?

Comment: WHERE IS NOT NULL ?

Comment: `where isnull(City,'') <> ''` since you said it could have blanks which isn't the same as NULL

Comment: @AlexP - there are many questions on SO on handling null values.  Please search once.

Comment: You should also ask yourself the question whether adding a typical presentation row in the dataretrieval query.

Comment: @techspider I did some searching but I think my forms plug-in is messing with me as it does work fine on SQL MS. Your code did work to remove the null/blank value

Comment: @Ako sorry i don't understand your comment

Comment: I also believe this  `select 'Select a City' as City, 'All' as Value` should not be from your DB but it should be part of your UI and append other values.

Comment: @techspider yes that select statement i added so when a user does not select any value it adds 'All' into my query-string. As i'm using a grid with a query listening to query-string parameters for sorting data.

Comment: `All` should have been added to the control directly instead of adding to the result from the query

Comment: @techspider I was going to say the same thing, just add another value to your observable collection, don't have the database "make" this dummy record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the responses it gave me a lot of insight on where to look for my problem. The original query with the addition of the below achieved the proper result.

working query:

```
select 'Select a City' as City, 'All' as Value
UNION ALL
select distinct City, City as Value from BND_Listing
where isnull(City,'') <> ''
Order by City ASC
```

with 'Select a City' always at the top of the dropdown. Credit to @scsimon on my other post for this.

```
with cte as(
select 'Select a City' as City, 'All' as Value
UNION ALL
select distinct City, City as Value from BND_Listing
where isnull(City,'') <> '')


select * from cte  Order by case when City = 'Select a City' then 1 else 2     end, City ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to add a row to your result, which is always on top and carries a NULL as ID?

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT NULL AS col1,'select an object' AS col2,0 AS SortInx
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 10 object_id,name,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name)
    FROM sys.objects
) AS Sortable
ORDER BY SortInx
```

Short explanation: `ROW_NUMBER()` start with `1`, so the first row gets `0` as sort index. The numbers from 1 to x represent the sorted name's order.

The outer `SELECT` will sort the result-set again making sure, that 0 is in front and 1 to x following...

Comment: you don't need outer SELECT since the list will be already sorted with ROW_NUMBER

Comment: Missing where is not null

Comment: @techspider Yes, but you cannot be sure, that the additional row will not appear somewhere in the middle... Even if this might be to anxious, one should never rely on implicit order if order matters...

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks for your example, this is a bit beyond me however. I'm still new to TSQL. I don't really understand the above. Time to pull out my handy SQL for dummies. lol

Comment: @AlexP, It's not that difficult... The inner select unions a *one-row-quey* with a result-set. You cannot predict the final order, so we have to force it. Sort this **after the `UNION`** will sort the "select an object" somewhere into the list. By using `0` in the leading row and `ROW_NUMBER()` to number all later rows from 1 to x we have a sorting predicat which can be used from the outer `SELECT`.

Comment: @Shnugo thanks for this explanation. I'm tinkering with it in SQL MS now. Thank you!

Comment: @Shnugo - my bad!! I don't know why I thought so this time :) It might be my time to leave for home!! You may add `order of rows is not guaranteed unless ORDER BY clause is applied` to your answer :)

Comment: @AlexP, I like the word *tinkering* :-) Please accept my answer if it solves your issue. And just to mention it: I think that some comments are right to re-think the approach. Such *"select one"* values in drop-boxes should rather be added later in the application...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with most of the comments here where the best approach is to actually have the "Select a Value" row added in the application itself. It's probably best to have the database only delivering "actual" data to your application and handle things like that in the code.

I'm also not sure what this project is for, but if you have access, I would strongly recommend creating views and/or stored procedures at the database level to abstract any database schema and logic changes from your application.

Just out of curiosity, why are you selecting the same field twice with different aliases? I'm assuming you're setting the display value and the actual value in a simple HTML dropdown, but in this case, the values are the same, so you could only have one field in your result set and reference that value twice in the application. Doing this would solve the problem of your original question, as well as simplify your query (although a query this simple is going to have negligible cost anyway) to look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT City
FROM BND_Listing (NOLOCK)
WHERE City IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Depending on the data, DB config, etc, you may need to account for empty strings and/or leading/trailing spaces with something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LTRIM(RTRIM(City)) AS City
FROM BND_Listing (NOLOCK)
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(City)) <> '' 
    AND City IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 1
```

Sorry...I know that may have been a little overkill, but you said you were new to SQL, so I thought I'd just share that in case your NULL results were actually empty strings.

Comment: thank you for these examples. I'm still trying to plug-in my fields/data into Shnugo's query example. I'm trying to build a directory of data similar to YP.com I have 2 tables 1 containing listing data another containing listing categories. I'm not writing this whole application out in notepad i'm not at that level.

Comment: I'm using the DNN CMS using 2 modules ActionForm & ActionGrid that allow me to create buttons and run a SQL query once the button is clicked. Using this i've set my grid to listen for query-strings with a where clause and i'm using the form to pass in these query-string values in order to achieve a "Sorted" directory of information. Sorted by Category, City, State, Country. I hope this makes sense alot of the terminology used thus far i'm reading into.

Comment: I'm just getting down select & where statements everything else is still new to me so i'm trying to understand what these queries do. Also due to the nature of my module I must pass in an example.com/Category/ALL when a user decides not to select ANY option from my dropdown so it pulls in data. Hope this makes sense. I have another post with some screenshots of my tools here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607263/using-union-to-pull-data-into-grid/39608379#39608379

Comment: @Anthony, Just as a side node [Bad habit to kick: NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Comment: @Shnugo - haha...yeah I know. I'm not usually working with application databases, but databases with huge tables where table locking IS  big issue, so most of those bad habits aren't relevant for me. That's a great article though. Saving it to pass on to some junior devs. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @AlexP gotcha. I'm not familiar with DNN (also not a .NET guy), but if I can be of any help with your sql queries, I'm happy to help. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Anthony I appreciate it. Stackoverflow is kickass i had always stumbled upon useful info here but never decided to join until recently.

Comment: Same here. I use this site probably 800 times every day, so I figured I should start contributing. :)